# Create a naming convention in CLion with a regular expression

Tags: c++, clion, jetbrains-ide

I want to "create a new naming convention" inside CLion.

Basically I use `camelCase` or `PascalCase` for my project, but I want to be able to write acronyms or abbreviations in `ALLCAPS`.
For example I want to be able to write `class FPS` or `int componentID` like that without a warning.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Do you have a comprehensive list of all the acronyms & abbreviations that you want to allow as allcaps?

Comment: Actually, i think i do. And even if its not complete, it is a good enough workaround as im becoming aware that its not possible. If you answer this question with that solution, i will mark it as valid.